# Create clean/blank MacOS filesystem for testing OSS

Tags: linux

In developing/testing OSS libraries I can replicate a clean Linux fs using containers. However, if I want to test oss libs for MacOS end users, I seem to be in a bit of a quandary. Is there any way to create a clean fs on MacOS that I can test libraries with? Perhaps using `chroot`? Can someone explain exactly instead of just saying "use chroot"?

Comment: Or you can just run containers on Mac?

Comment: containers on macos have a linux fs tmk, but maybe you could get close, maybe there is a Docker image that attempts to be very close

Comment: It’s not clear from your question whether or not you need to test your library as running on macOS or on Linux.

Comment: ultimately I am trying to create a barebones MacOS fs..i think chroot on MacOS is the cheapest and simplest? but idk how to use chroot.

Comment: is it not clear what I am trying to do? i have a MacOS laptop, but i have things like coreutils installed and other MacOS users might not have that installed, etc.

Comment: what do you mean by macOS fs? You need to create an empty APFS partition? Give a concrete and specific example of how you need to test your library.

Comment: i need to test the lib like a non-root user on the average barebones MacOS machine dogg, nothin too crazy

Comment: if those libraries are installed in your own user account, then just create a new user and switch to it when you want to test.

Comment: yes but there a global tools that are available at that command line, other users on my machine would have access to those tools, which i want to avoid

Comment: can you modify how they are installed so they are localized to one user? I know that’s how I install Macports.

Comment: @RibaldEddie might work i am not sure

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you need a blank disk?

Answer (score 1):

Run MacOS as a virtual machine on Linux using VirtualBox? That might not be possible, since MacOS might only run on MacOS hardware. In that case, you might have to spin up a MacOS VM on a Mac computer.

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-run-MacOS-on-Linux-in-a-Virtual-Machine

Comment: The first sentence in the link you shared says, "Like Keith Derrick writes running macOS on anything but apple hardware violates the eula".

Comment: @Lucas: Worse. It is a DMCA violation. Psystar who tried making money selling PCs with MacOS installed was ordered to pay $2,500 per PC due to DMCA violation. Didn’t matter though since they were broke and never paid anyone, including their lawyers.

Answer (score 0):

What do you actually want to achieve? You can take an external hard drive, attach it to a Mac, format it using Disk Utility. Or you can create a disk image on your hard drive. Or you can just partition your hard drive, and such a partition can be completely separate from other partitions (with its own login, no access to other partitions)